# DevDay 2015 - Belo Horizonte, Brasil

Tags: debate

## O SOpt está patrocinando o [DevDay 2015](http://devday.devisland.com)!

O DevDay é uma conferência de um dia, que acontece há 5 anos em Belo Horizonte - MG, com palestras sobre diversos temas relacionados à computação e tecnologia. O evento desse ano vai acontecer dia 31 de Outubro e o Stack Overflow em Português é um dos patrocinadores.

Uma das palestras esse ano será sobre a arquitetura do Stack Overflow, apresentada pela [Roberta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/901/rla4), uma das nossas desenvolvedoras. Quem tiver curiosidade de saber como nós mantemos tudo funcionando (na maior parte das vezes), pode assistir.

Como parte do patrocínio, nós recebemos 4 entradas que serão sorteadas entre vocês.
Quem tiver interesse e puder estar em **Belo Horizonte dia 31 de Outubro**, basta deixar uma resposta nesse tópico aqui. Lembrando que os gastos de transporte são por sua conta. Nós estamos dando apenas a inscrição da conferência.

Repetindo:
**Quem quiser um ingresso para o DevDay, responda a essa pergunta!**

**Os ingressos serão sorteados (aleatoriamente) daqui 1 semana, dia 04/09/2015.**
**Edit:** Ah, esqueci de falar que o sorteio não vai levar em consideração os votos na sua resposta. Vai ser totalmente aleatório, então todo mundo tem a mesma chance.

Divirtam-se!

## UPDATE

O sorteio será feito hoje às **14h** (horário de Brasília - muito profissional).

Quem ainda não sabe se quer participar, melhor correr!

## RESULTADO!

Procurei um jeito de conseguir fazer o sorteio, que me deixasse botar o nome de todo mundo e sortear os 4 ganhadores. Queria um site que tivesse um permalink, pra dar um grau a mais de autenticidade e confiança de que o sorteio realmente aconteceu, e foi aleatório.

Procurei, mas não encontrei. Achei alguns serviços que faziam bem mais que isso. E outros que faziam exatamente o que queria, mas que eram pagos...
Devo dizer que fiquei meio desapontado.

Não queria fazer um sorteio que pudesse dar margem à desconfianças. Todos vocês tem a mesma chance de ganhar, e é importante que todo mundo confiasse no resultado. Que não houve manipulação.

No final das contas, não foi possível encontrar. Então decidi seguir o caminho mais fácil...

[image: E VOCÊ VAI PRA CONFERÊNCIA!]

Temos 20 inscritos para ganhar o ingresso. Que é um número excepcional de pessoas, que fazem parte da mesma comunidade, que poderiam aproveitar a conferência juntos.

Não seria excelente se, ao invés de escolher apenas 4 e deixar outros 16 com o pires na mão, todo mundo ganhasse um ingresso e pudesse ir? **Seria!**

Então é isso. Nós decidimos dar o ingresso a todos vocês que tem disponibilidade de ir, e aproveitar a conferência para um semi-encontro-informal. Onde vocês podem ver as palestras, aprender coisas novas, conhecer mais gente... Enfim... Aproveitar o dia lá.

Eu vou entrar em contato com cada um de vocês sobre seus ingressos assim que eles estiverem disponíveis.

**Parabéns a todos, e aproveitem a conferência!**

---

A pergunta foi protegida porque todos os ganhadores já estão listado aqui, então não tem porque adicionar mais respostas.

Comment: Math continua o campeão mundial de editar meus posts!

Comment: @MathPasquale,haha

Comment: Quem me dera ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. Falando nisso... Acho que já passou da hora da gente tentar patrocinar alguma coisa em Portugal, mas eu não faço ideia de por onde começar. Acha que o pessoal daí teria disposição de me ajudar?

Comment: Uhul! Mal posso esperar! :D

Comment: Vão vir aqui na minha cidade?

Comment: @Gabe não sei porquê mas não vi a notificação do seu comentário. Me parece uma ótima ideia. Se quiseres posso fazer um levantamento do que há para patrocinar por cá, até posso representar o site se necessário.

Comment: @JorgeB. Seria uma boa ajuda. A gente pode organizar um post no Meta com sugestões do pessoal de Portugal. O que acha?

Comment: @Gabe parece-me um ótima ideia mais uma vez.

Comment: @JorgeB. Ótimo! Eu não vou ter tempo hoje, mas se quiser criar o post, sinta-se a vontade!

Comment: Uai, tô dentro sô! Esse trem vai ser bão demais da conta! (P.S. Já tenho ingresso pra esse evento, por isso não estou entrando no sorteio)

Comment: cadê o resultado? já são 2 minutos de atraso agora!

Comment: @Math Eu tava almoçando!

Answer (score 17):

[image: Quero]

Aproveito pra conhecer os bacanas de BH. Partiu agilizar evento, moçada.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Eu quero muito ir]
Developers ! What's your profession ??? Code ! Code ! Code !

Evento top em BH. Quero muito ir.

Answer (score 11):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em 2013 foi muito top. \o/
2015 será melhor ainda!

Se mais alguém for, podemos marcar algo. :D

Comment: Cara, eu fui em 2013 também, muito massa... esse ano tambem vai estar muito top.

Comment: Vou ver se dessa vez eu vou "com tempo". Pq em 2013, eu saí na madrugada e voltei logo após a penúltima palestra.

Answer (score 11):

Estou esperando o sorteio!!

Meu café-da-manhã vai ser assim :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se/Quando o @OnoSendai ver isso, ele vai querer voltar. kkkk

Comment: Verdade, kkkkkkk

Comment: Isso da saudade até em mim, que não sou de Minas

Comment: minhas chances de ganhar estão diminuindo!!!!

Answer (score 10):

Tô só na espreita desse sorteio.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 8):

Já to preparando a mala pra curtir a viajem pra BH!

Answer (score 7):

MAL POSSO ESPERAR !!!!!! MUITO BOM!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 6):

Chamaaa euuuu o//

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 6):

Developers what your profession?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 6):

```
if (eu.ganharIngresso()) {
  eu.setHumor(Humor.FELIZ);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Aguardando o resultado do sorteio kkk.

```
if($nomeGanhador == "Giulio"){
    echo "Feliz demais UAI!"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[image: Ahhh se eu não ganhar....]
Manda aqui esse ingresso pro papai...

Answer (score 4):

Uai só! Eu eu quero muito \m/!

Answer (score 4):

Tô dentro!

\o/ \o/ \o/ \o/

Answer (score 4):

Eu quero muito ir no DevDay 2015

Answer (score 4):

Eu quero também.

A oportunidade está aqui, só falta a sorte!

Answer (score 4):

Eu queroooooooo muito =D
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Eu quero esse ingresso. - Permissão negada.

sudo eu quero esse ingresso. - Pronto é seu.

Answer (score 4):

Quero participar;;;
Aguardando o Sorteio..

Answer (score 4):

Cara muleque, que código, que isso, põe eu pra participar!