# DevDay 2017 - Belo Horizonte

Tags: debate

## O SOpt está patrocinando o [DevDay 2017](http://devday.devisland.com)!

O DevDay é uma conferência de um dia, que acontece há 7 anos em Belo Horizonte - MG, com palestras sobre diversos temas relacionados à computação e tecnologia. O evento desse ano vai acontecer dia 02 de Setembro e, [assim como em 2015](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4268), o Stack Overflow em Português é um dos patrocinadores.

Como parte do patrocínio, nós recebemos 4 entradas que serão distribuidas entre vocês.

Diferentemente da vez passada, não vamos realizar um sorteio aleatório. As entradas serão dadas para as **4 pessoas que mais melhorarem posts** entre 27/07/2017 e 11/08/2017. Ou seja serão 15 dias para dar o seu melhor e ganhar um ingresso. Algumas regras básicas:

- Válido para qualquer usuário
- "Melhorarem posts" quer dizer as 4 melhores médias de votos depois da edição comparado aos votos antes da edição. Ou seja, não adianta sair fazendo um monte de edições menores. Precisam realmente melhorar o conteúdo.

Quem tiver interesse e puder estar em **Belo Horizonte dia 02 de Setembro**, prepare o teclado e boa sorte! Lembrando que os gastos de transporte são por sua conta. Nós estamos dando apenas a inscrição da conferência.

Repetindo:
**Quem quiser um ingresso para o DevDay, faça o máximo de edições possíveis entre amanhã e 11/08/2017**!

**O resultado será anunciado no sábado, 12/08/2017**.

Divirtam-se!

---

Além dos ingressos para a conferência, também estamos pensando em ter um **Encontro SOpt em Belo Horizonte**. Mas, para isso, precisamos saber quantos de vocês tem interesse e condição de participar.

Os encontros são normalmente realizados em um bar ou local público, e o único intuito é sentar, conversar, e conhecer melhor quem participa do site. Nós bancamos a conta

Quem estiver afim, basta votar na resposta abaixo. Assim eu posso saber se há um bom número de pessoas interessadas e começar a organizar as coisas! Além de vocês, também teremos alguns palestrantes do DevDay convidados, então é uma boa oportunidade de trocar uma ideia com eles.

Espero que vocês possam participar!

### Atualização:

Podemos ter um encontro no sábado, 02/09, depois da conferência, também. Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Já prepararam a query para isso?

Comment: As postagens de outras pessoas que eu editar também contam? Ou só as minhas postagens?

Comment: Segundo o site, o evento se encerrará as 18:30, porque nao rola esse encontro no dia 2?

Comment: @Gabe não era interessante arranjar um evento em Portugal para o SOpt patrocinar? Bem pelo menos para mim e para os outros portugas de certeza que era ;)

Comment: @Francisco Sim! Qualquer edição, em qualquer post.

Comment: @JorgeB. Infelizmente apenas um evento de Portugal entrou em contato até hoje. Se aparecerem mais, certamente gostaria de fazer. Assim como outro encontro por aí, mas isso depende de verba

Comment: @Articuno Não é uma má ideia. Vou pensar a respeito e, se necessário, edito daqui a pouco.

Comment: @Gabe eu posso tentar agilizar alguma coisa por aqui. Agora até a [websummit](https://websummit.com) é em Lisboa pelo segundo ano consecutivo.

Comment: @Gabe Caso eu edite e ganhe alguns upvotes com isso, e outra pessoa vai la, edita por cima e ganha outros upvotes, eu vou recebe-los também ou somente a pessoa que editou depois?

Comment: @Francisco Recebe também

Comment: em 2015 foi muito legal ! recomendo a todos a participar desse desafio \o/ !

Comment: @Gabe O evento foi fantástico! Obrigado a todos da equipe do SO! Espero ter mais ano que vem. =)

Answer (score 12):

## Sim, eu tenho disponibilidade para um Encontro SOpt em BH

#### (entre os dias 01/09 a 03/09)