# SOpt Tour - Brasil

Tags: debate, meetup

Como foi anunciado, o SOpt é um dos [patrocinadores do DevDay](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6216) esse ano. E vamos ter um encontro em Belo Horizonte, naquele fim de semana. Para aproveitar a viagem, gostaria também de ter outro encontro SOpt, em algum lugar do Brasil. Mas... não sei onde!

Então preciso da ajuda de vocês! Onde vocês gostariam que houvesse um encontro? Rio de Janeiro? Recife? Curitiba? Porto Alegre? Qualquer lugar é lugar, só precisamos que haja um bom número de pessoas dispostas a comparecer.

*Idealmente*, deve acontecer no **segundo fim de semana de setembro (dias 08 a 10)**. E eu, particularmente, gostaria que acontecesse em outra cidade que não fosse São Paulo. Todos os outros encontros aconteceram por lá, e seria bacana dar a chance a outros lugares. Mas caso não haja possibilidade, sem problema algum termos um em SP.

É isso...

## Onde podemos fazer um encontro SOpt, entre 08-10/09/2017?

Dêem suas sugestões abaixo, e votem nas que puderem comparecer!

Comment: Aluga um motorhome e faz encontro itinerante :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Já pensou se a empresa é doida o suficiente pra me botar num carango e me deixar solto na BR-101?

Comment: Eu imagino que seja!

Comment: E aí, ninguém vai propor nada fora do eixo Sul-Sudeste?

Comment: @bfavaretto Nem pra eu ir passar um tempo no Nordeste....

Comment: RJ, um churrascão!

Comment: Seria legal se depois desse houvesse um em Salvador - BA

Answer (score 14):

### Eu gostaria de um encontro em Curitiba

Comment: Curitibaaaaaaa!

Comment: Vou estar uma semana antes em Curitiba. Qse coincidiu pra mim. :-/

Comment: @acklay tenta reagendar aí :P quanto mais gente participar melhor.

Comment: @rray Não vou conseguir porque exatamente no dia 8, meu pai vai estar vindo lá do Norte de Minas aqui pra casa aqui em São Paulo. Tenho esse compromisso no primeiro fim de semana de setembro que daria pra mim, não coincidiu. Queria muito mas desta vez não vai dar pra mim. Quem sabe no próximo. Que aliás, acho que vocês (nós da comunidade) no entendemos tão bem e falamos tanto em comum (acredito eu) que não faz muito sentido ficar muito tempo sem encontros.

Answer (score 8):

## São Paulo - Capital, o que acham? :) :) :)

Answer (score 7):

### Eu gostaria de um encontro em Porto Alegre

Answer (score 5):

### Eu gostaria de um encontro em Portugal :) Manda o JNat para cá ;)

Comment: Eu também! Mas só dá pra voar pra um lugar por vêz!

Comment: @Gabe ficamos a espera da próxima ;)

Answer (score 3):

### Eu gostaria de um encontro no Rio de Janeiro

Answer (score 3):

## Que tal (Bela e) Santa Catarina (Florianópolis ou Região de Blumenau)?

> Quem compareceria comente e de um Up!

Comment: Sou de Blumenau, mas posso comparecer em Floripa tbm

Answer (score 1):

**Guarulhos é perto do Aeroporto.**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Perto, naum .... "Que burro dá zero pra ele , professor Giraf...!"

Answer (score 0):

## Que tal um Tour do SOpt na cidade de São José dos Campos? ;D

Comment: Seria excelente!!!