# Vencedores do Ingresso - DevDay 2017

Tags: debate, concurso

Acabou o suspense!

Como [anunciado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6216), é hora de saber quem ganhou as entradas para o [DevDay 2017](http://devday.devisland.com/). Todos os premiados contribuiram bastante para o site nos últimos 15 dias, e vão poder assistir ótimas palestras durante a conferência.

A fórmula (feita com ajuda do primeiro PhD do Stack: [David Robinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712603/david-robinson)!) para o resultado é a seguinte:

```
            PrimUpvotes + (5 * Aceitos) + (10 * DvUpvotes) + (15 * DvAceitos)

PrimUpvotes:  "Votos em posts com 0 pontos antes da edição"
Aceitos:      "Aceitações após a edição"
DvUpvotes:    "Votos em posts negativados antes da edição"
DvAceitos:    "Aceitações em posts negativados antes da edição"
```

Os pesos diferentes são para priorizar o valor da edição. Conseguir reverter um post com pontuação negativa é um feito e tanto.

Então vamos aos vencedores:

#### 123 pontos: BSalvo

[image: perfil de Bsalvo em Stack Overflow em Português, Perguntas e respostas para programadores profissionais e entusiastas]

#### 34 pontos: Francisco

[image: perfil de Francisco em Stack Overflow em Português, Perguntas e respostas para programadores profissionais e entusiastas]

#### 15 pontos: LeonanCarvalho

[image: perfil de LeonanCarvalho em Stack Overflow em Português, Perguntas e respostas para programadores profissionais e entusiastas]

#### 10 pontos: gato

[image: perfil de gato em Stack Overflow em Português, Perguntas e respostas para programadores profissionais e entusiastas]

Parabéns! Vejo vocês no evento!

Vocês vão receber as informações na segunda feira, pelo email registrado aqui no SOpt. Então fiquem de olho (ou falem comigo).

## E não é só isso

A competição pelo ingresso valia apenas para quem pudesse estar em BH no dia 02/09/2017. Mas não é muito justo deixar todo o resto de fora...

Então as 102 pessoas que mais ganharam pontos nos últimos 15 dias vão receber adesivos do SOpt em casa!
<sup>Subi o número de vencedores para 102 porque todos estavam com a mesma pontuação, nada mais justo!</sup>

[image: Adesivos!]

#### A lista dos vencedores:

```
Nome                     Pontos
------------------------ ------
LINQ                     242
Virgilio Novic           116
Victor Stafusa           105
Anderson Carlos Woss     89
Leo Caracciolo           85
Articuno                 82
Isac                     61
Sorack                   57
bigown                   57
acklay                   54
José Diz                 53
Leonardo Bonetti         53
Perozzo                  52
PauloMaia                51
André Spironello         50
rLinhares                50
Math                     50
13dev                    43
Gustavo Fragoso          38
DNick                    32
Mateus A.                32
Sergio                   32
ℛɑƒæĿ                    31
Carlos Coelho            30
bfavaretto               30
Sidon                    30
Zulian                   29
Laércio Lopes            29
Vinicius                 29
Ricardo Moraleida        28
Marcos Henzel            28
Walmir Silva             28
Rovann Linhalis          26
Ciano Barbarossa         25
Victor Hugo Schmidt      22
Guilherme Nascimento     22
Renan                    21
Bianca C.                21
MasterLima               20
Luciano Pedrosa          20
Yuri Fernandes           20
Otto                     19
Inkeliz                  19
Bruno H.                 18
RHER WOLF                17
Marconi                  17
Leone Cerqueira          17
Wéllingthon M. de Souza  16
Wallace Maxters          15
rray                     15
Dorathoto                13
Marconcilio Souza        13
Rafael Salomão           12
Edvaldo Silva            11
Mariana Ferreira         11
Guilherme Padovam        11
Amadeu Antunes           11
MarceloBoni              11
Eduardo Almeida          11
Ricardo91                10
Dani Guido               10
Joaquim da Silveira Maia 10
McJesus                  10
Victor Hugo Lopes        10
Elder Son                10
João Dias                10
gato                     10
MagicHat                 10
VME                      10
Lucas Costa              10
thiago ubiratan          10
Bruno                    10
Rafael Chaves            10
Ronda                    10
Everson D. Ferreira      10
LeonardoEbert            10
Renato Silva             10
rayraisemeup             10
Nanokaso Gongon          10
Tmc                      10
David Samm               9
Marcelo de Andrade       9
Miguel Angelo            8
Fernando Silveira        8
Bruno Rigolon            8
Ayrton Giffoni           8
Rafael Acioly            8
Randrade                 7
ramaral                  7
Igor Venturelli          7
João Regis               7
Pedro Corso              7
Dudaskank                7
Rafael Cunha             7
Ezequiel Messore         7
Gustavo Souza            7
thiago Bernardo          7
Tony Montana             7
```

De novo, parabéns à todos!

Também fiquem de olho nos seus emails, que o formulário vai chegar na segunda feira!

## Query

Atendendo aos pedidos, aqui vai [uma versão da query](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/713335/peso-das-edicoes) usada para encontrar os vencedores, no Data Explorer. Com algumas considerações:

1. Alguns filtros (tipo votos próprios em posts que você editou) não puderam ser aplicados, pela restrição da tabela de votos
2. Os resultados são bem diferentes porque no SEDE os votos não têm horário, apenas data. Então a maior parte dos votos acaba sendo desconsiderada, porque não foram dados "antes" ou "depois" das edições, já que aconteram no mesmo dia.

Divirtam-se

## Atualização DevDay

Pessoal que estiver na conferência, ou que for ao [encontro](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6275), tem uma sala de chat especial pra vocês conversarem entre si: [DevDay 2017](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64989/devday-2017)

Comment: E cade a lista desses 100? :p

Comment: @Articuno o jeito vai ser colocar num gist!

Comment: Não tem jeito de fazer uma query no data.se nao?

Comment: Obrigado! Estou muito feliz de estar entre os ganhadores do ingresso. Mas me surgiu uma dúvida: Os ganhadores do ingresso também vão receber os adesivos do SOpt?

Comment: @Francisco na conferência 

Comment: Tá pedindo login e senha pra acessar o gist

Comment: @Articuno Botei como trecho de código

Comment: Considerando que o ingresso seja "intransferível", e se algum desses ganhadores não se manifestarem, o que vai acontecer?! Será anunciado um próximo da lista? Ou será perdido o ingresso?!

Comment: @acklay Vai pro próximo da lista, até acabar a que eu tenho (de pessoas que disseram poder ir no encontro em BH). Depois disso, vai pra primeira pessoa dessa lista que puder estar na conferência

Comment: @Gabe não entendi muito bem. "Até acabar a que eu tenho..." Se eu falar que tenho interesse em ir, você disponibiliza pra mim?! hehe

Comment: @acklay Eu vou tentar primeiro com as pessoas que disseram poder ir no encontro em BH. Se essa lista esgotar e sobrarem ingressos, aí começo a ver no site em geral. Você tá bem no alto `;)`

Comment: Que show! Primeira vez que recebo prêmio assim. Estou ativo na comunidade tem cerca de 2 meses, mas isso só me faz querer continuar contribuindo. Obrigado!

Comment: @AyrtonGiffoni Que bom! Bem vindo! (E continue editando! )

Comment: Feliz por ter ganhado também, obrigado!

Comment: Putz, eu não imaginei que o ingresso só iria valer pro pessoal que votou na resposta 

Comment: Aeww, poxa feliz demais em ganhar !

Comment: Vai ser uma honra poder participar desse evento :)

Comment: @Gabe pode ser :)

Comment: Chegaram os adesivos.... que comunidade incrível!

Comment: Meus adesivos chegaram ! Obrigado Stack Overflow

Comment: DevDay 2018 já tem as inscrições abertas, esse ano vai ter o concurso de novo? Ano passado foi bem legal! @Juan