# Encontro SOpt - Belo Horizonte, MG - 02/09/2017

Tags: debate, meetup

O SOpt vai [patrocinar o DevDay 2017](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6216), em Belo Horizonte!

Junto com isso, aproveitando o evento, vamos também ter o primeiro encontro em BH<sup>1</sup>, onde qualquer um de vocês pode chegar, comer, beber, conversar sobre programação (ou qualquer outra coisa) e ir pra casa feliz e contente. Por nossa conta!

Melhor que isso, só *Zelda: Breath of the Wild*<sup>2</sup>.

O encontro vai ser combinado com o *happy hour* do DevDay, então além de nós também estarão presentes organizadores e palestrantes do evento. É uma boa chance de vocês conhecerem pessoas de outros lugares, programadores e programadoras como vocês.

O local ainda vai ser definido, com o pessoal do evento, mas já podem marcar na sua agenda:
**Se vocês estiver em BH ou redondezas na noite do dia 02/09/2017, já tem lugar pra jantar!**

Não há necessidade de uma lista formal de convidados, mas eu preciso ter uma ideia de quantas pessoas podem ir, então **deem um voto na resposta, se você acredita que poderá comparecer**.

tl;dr:

**O que**: Encontro SOpt- Belo Horizonte

**Quando**: 02/09/2017, a partir das 19:00

**Onde**: [Restaurante Filé Espeto & Cia](http://www.restaurantefile.com.br)
Av. Fleming, 271 • Bairro Ouro Preto • Belo Horizonte / MG

**Como**: [Confirme sua presença](https://www.sympla.com.br/dev-day-2017---happy-hour__181164) e apareça!

---

<sup>1. Ou segundo, se contar o almoço de todo mundo no DevDay 2015</sup> 
<sup>2. Recomendo</sup>

Comment: [Zelda !](https://youtu.be/AKYn4ACAd7s?t=25s)

Comment: @BrunoCosta Eu vou assistir Zelda Symphony esse ano!

Comment: Como foi? Tem fotos?

Answer (score 7):

## Eu posso ir no Encontro em BH, dia 02/09/2017

[image: Schwarzenegger Mineiro]

## Lembre de [confirmar](https://www.sympla.com.br/dev-day-2017---happy-hour__181164) sua participação

Comment: To partindo pra BH daqui a pouco heim!